# fitCenter Algorithm ImageView

Tags: java, android, scaling

How ImageView fitCenter algorithm works , i have a image_hight and image_width , i need to programmatically implement the centerFit ,, but i'm having no luck with it ,, i tried t scale image like this

```
newPostHolder.height = DeviceHigh;
 int heightOfImage = data.getInt("image_height");
                    if (heightOfImage > ((newPostHolder.height / 100) * 80) || heightOfImage == newPostHolder.height) {
                        heightOfImage = ((newPostHolder.height / 100) * 69);
                    }

                    newPostHolder.one_imageview.getLayoutParams().height = heightOfImage;
```

And like this

```
int heightOfImage = 0;
int widthOfImage = 0;

float scalingRatio = ((Float.parseFloat(heightOfImage) / Float.parseFloat(widthOfImage));

 viewHolder.imageLoadingLayout.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(scalingRatio*width );
```

the first one big images still looks tall and the second one do some type of blurring on images.

My question is how can i scale the image like the fitCenter scale ??

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this "blurring" effect on images?

Comment: i will try , but i already changed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the second code works like the fitCenter my problem was that i do a check before fixing the size and thats check cuzes the problem

```
 int heightOfImage = data.getInt("image_height");
 int widthOfImage = data.getInt("image_width");
 heightOfImage = newPostHolder.width  * heightOfImage / widthOfImage;
 newPostHolder.one_imageview.getLayoutParams().height = heightOfImage;
 newPostHolder.one_imageview.getLayoutParams().width = newPostHolder.width;
```